# ng-repeat over a multidimensional array in Rails + Angular app with Postgres database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, postgresql, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a Rails + Angular project where I have a multidimensional array `poem` that contains an array of lines, which then contains an array of words and their associated links. For example:

```
[
    [
        [link: "www.google.com", word: "google"], [link: "www.google.com", word: "google-Two"] 
    ], 

    [    
        [link: "www.yahoo.com", word: "yahoo"], [link: "www.yahoo.com", word: "yahoo-TWo"]
    ],

];
```

I'm having difficulty accessing the data through the Angular controller. I've entered some dummy data through the Rails console for now, and when I log it in my Rails server, it looks like this:

```
Started GET "/poems/8" for ::1 at 2015-12-14 18:31:27 -0500
Processing by PoemsController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"8"}
  Poem Load (12.3ms)  SELECT  "poems".* FROM "poems" WHERE "poems"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 8]]
{:linkToGIF=>"www.google.com", :word=>"google"}
{:linkToGIF=>"www.google.com", :word=>"google-Two"}
{:linkToGIF=>"www.yahoo.com", :word=>"yahoo"}
{:linkToGIF=>"www.yahoo.com", :word=>"yahoo-TWo"}
  Rendered poems/show.json.jbuilder (1.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 25ms (Views: 9.9ms | ActiveRecord: 12.3ms)
```

But on the Angular side, it looks like this:

[image: Poem data in browser console]

When it comes back from the database, the entire word object is wrapped in quotes, and appears to be a string—even though I've entered it correctly through the console. So, I can't dot into the `linkToGIF` and `word` properties, and if I try to do a nested ng-repeat with `(key, value)`, it iterates over each character in the string. Here's what I have in my Angular template:

```
<div id="poem-display">
  <div ng-repeat="lines in showCtrl.onePoem.poem track by $index">
    <h4>Line {{$index + 1}}</h4>
    <div id="line-display">
      <div id="word-display" ng-repeat="(arrayIndex, wordData) in lines track by $index">
        <div ng-repeat="(newIndex, newValue) in wordData track by $index">
          <!-- in the following ng-repeat, `anotherValue` is just one character in the string, beginning with {, ", l, i, n, k, etc.  -->
          <!-- <div ng-repeat="(anotherIndex, anotherValue) in newValue track by $index"> -->
            <!-- anotherIndex:anotherValue is: {{anotherIndex}}:{{anotherValue}} -->
            ...
          <!-- </div> -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For reference, this is what my schema looks like:

```
  create_table "poems", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title",                   null: false
    t.string   "author",                  null: false
    t.text     "poem",       default: [], null: false, array: true
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
  end
```

And here's the show.json.jbuilder:

```
json.extract! @poem, :id, :title, :author, :poem, :created_at, :updated_at
```

I've tried a bunch of different fixes, but no luck yet. If anyone has any suggestions, I'd love to hear them. Unfortunately, using something other than Rails/Postgres isn't really an option, since this is for an assignment where I *have* to use Rails + Angular.

Comment: tried using `JSON.parse(obj)` ?

Comment: @svarog yeah, I tried that. No luck, unfortunately!